# REST controller returns HTML page - good practice?

Tags: java, spring, rest, frontend

last time I found a example of REST app, which one REST controller returns HTML page(index.html). As a front-end was used Vue.JS and other communication was realized by REST controller returning normal JSON. 
And now I stil thing how this solution looks in context of good practice of building REST API.

I add link to this controller. [Home Controller](https://github.com/arocketman/SpringBlog/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arocketman/github/controllers/HomeController.java)

Ok. I read something and now I know that is a standard mechanism to serving view in Spring. 
And now I see that `HomeController` is not Rest because have annotations `@Controller` not `@RestController`. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Where in REST it states that you can only use JSON? ReST is about content negotiation and returning HTML is perfectly fine... However I highly doubt it was a rest controller and just a regular controller serving the starting index file.

Comment: I looked again to the code and I decide add link to this code. [Home Controller](https://github.com/arocketman/SpringBlog/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arocketman/github/controllers/HomeController.java). And what do think about this? Of course I ask only about this controller.

Comment: That is just a regular controller and not a REST controller.

Answer (score 0):

Of course NOT , Rest is use to send state information and not the UI

for UI we have other conrtoller to be used.

REST must be used when we need to send or recieve state information in form of json preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good programming paradigm to return JSON/XML as response to a rest call. This is separation of concern. Once the response is obtained from the Rest call we should process that to render an html object. Also this will ensure that if your rendering engine changes you will not have to change the code for the rest call. eg. You can change your view from struts to angular then your rest api code remains unchanged.